# Static and Dynamic linking in Visual studio

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012, dll

I understand the concept of Static and Dynamic linking. It is known that on Windows platform, `.dll` are the dynamic libraries and `.lib` are the static libraries.

**My Confusion:** I made a project in which I had to use the OpenCV libraries. Basically, I had to use the following 5 libraries of OpenCV:

```
-lopencv_core
-lopencv_highgui
-lopencv_imgcodecs
-lopencv_imgproc
-lopencv_videoio
```

For this purpose, in the properties of the project, I had to tell the **compiler**  the path of the libraries in the `Additional Library Directory` of VS 2012 and I also had to tell **linker** about the `.lib` libraries which I want to use for the project. The project got compiled without any error. But when I try to ran the project, it said that `videoio.dll` is missing (same error for rest of the libraries too). As soon as I copied the `.dll` files inside the folder where the `.exe` was present, the project ran fine.

**Question:** Why did I have to copy the `.dll` files when I already linked the static libraries (`.lib`)?

**Further Question:** When I use Eclipse on Mac OS or Linux, I just have to tell the complier where the OpenCV libraries are present and to the linker which other OpenCV libraries I want to use. I never had to put the dynamic libraries to the `.exe` folder in that case.

Comment: In VisualStudio there usually is a .lib file along to each .dll files. Those differ from static libraries as they are called import libraries. You need those for linking your (dynamic) dlls. In OpenCV the static libs are in the `staticlib` folder whereas the import libs are in the `lib` folder. The dynamic libraries (dlls) can be found in the `bin` folder. So if you want to link statically, you'll have to use the libs from the `staticlib` directory.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The "usual" windows tool chains offer two "flavours" of .lib.

One is the static libraries you mention. When used, there is no associated .dll.

The other is a stripped library that is only there to hook in the code to load and fix functions pointers for the dynamic library at load time.

With dynamic libraries (the .dll) you can either load it your self (via. `LoadLibrary`) or you can use the stub (import) .lib you have been provided with the .dll. Favour the import .lib if one is provided.

> Why did I had to copy the .dll files when I already linked the static libraries (.lib) ?

The .dll needs to be in the path, or the directory with the .exe for the loader to find it.

---

> How do I differentiate whether the .lib file is Static library or Dynamic library?

Generally the documentation should include some level of detail about this. If they are lumped in the same folder, then I would assume the .lib is tied to the .dll. If all else fails, look at the file size; if the .lib is tied to the .dll, then it is normally small in comparison to the .dll.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand, I just have `.lib` files and `.dll` files for OpenCV libraries. How do I differentiate whether the `.lib` file is Static library or Dynamic library ?

Comment: Generally the documentation should include some level of detail about this. Else, if they are lumped in the same folder, then I would assume the .lib is tied to the .dll. If all else fails, the file size. If the .lib is tied to the .dll, then it is normally small in comparison to the .dll.

Comment: I have checked the folder of OpenCV where I have build my librairs using Visual Studio. In the `build` folder, among several folders, I have `bin` and `lib` folders too. In the `lib` folder, I have files with extensions `.lib` and `.exp`. And, in the `bin` folder, I have files with extensions `.dll` and `.pdb`. Does it mean that I do not have static libaries of OpenCV at all?

Comment: @user2756695. I suspect you have not built the static libraries, only the dynamic libraries with the associated import libraries.