# OpenCV's Static and Shared libraries in Mac OS

Tags: c++, macos, opencv

I asked a [question about static and dynamic libraries in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32562242/static-and-dynamic-linking-in-visual-studio/32562340#32562340) but I am still not 100% able to get the concept. In Mac OS, the dynamic libraries have the extension `.dylib`. I have installed OpenCV-3.0 using the following steps:

```
# make a separate directory for building
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ..

make 
sudo make install
```

After following the above steps, I got the header files of OpenCV in `/usr/local/include` and the libraries of OpenCV in `/usr/local/lib`.

**Confusion:** In `/usr/local/lib`, I can see only the libraries with `.dylib` for all the important libraries of OpenCV, for example `-lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui, -lopencv_imgcodecs, -lopencv_imgproc, -lopencv_videoio`. Though there are some libraries with extension `.a` but those are not related to important OpenCV libraries.

Where are the static libraries in Mac OS? or Did I skip any step and therefore, static libraries were not installed in my system?

Comment: @Marco: thanks, changed it.

Comment: Did you read this ? http://shiffman.net/2011/01/23/how-to-build-opencv-static-libraries-mac-os-x/    from what I understand either you build dynamic or you build static, to have the static version you need to specify not to compile dynamic.