# Runtime libraries and Static libraries of OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I have posted two question before about static and dynamic libaries and got satisfactory responses. But still there are some missing links.

I am able to solve my problem but I did not understand the complete concept.

**Concept to be understand:** Through the response in my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32562242/static-and-dynamic-linking-in-visual-studio) , I realized that I do not have static libraries of OpenCV, so I installed them. Now, I have static libraries of OpenCV in Windows 7.

I made a simple program as given below to test the functionalityof static libraries of OpenCV.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv\highgui.h"
#include "opencv2\core\core.hpp"
#include "opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp"

int main()
{
    cv::Mat image(100, 500, CV_8SC3, Scalar(0,0,255));
    std::cout << "\nstatic Libs test"<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

For the linking of above code, I have used the static libraries of OpenCV.

**Real Question:** The above code gets compiled, linked and run without any issue if I choose `Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)` runtime libraries in Visual Studio. But if I choose `Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd)` runtime libraries then, there are a lot of erros which look like following (I have not included all the errors):

```
Error   1   error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MTd_StaticDebug' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in Source.obj 
Error   22  error LNK2005: "public: __cdecl std::_Container_base12::_Container_base12(void)" (??0_Container_base12@std@@QEAA@XZ) already defined in opencv_core2411d.lib(alloc.obj)
```

I just want to understand the reason of such conflict between the DLL runtime libraries of C++ and Static libraries of OpenCV. After choosing `Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)`, are the C++ libraries are also getting linked statically?

And lastly, which runtime library option should be selected if I want to link few openCV libraries statically and few dynamically (situation might seem awkward but just asking)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Some background**

The [`/MT` and `/MD`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3.aspx) with their debug equivalents (`/xxd`) link in the C++ runtime differently.

- `/MD` links to the dll version of the C++ runtime
- `/MT` to the static library version (i.e. what is required of the C++ runtime in linked into your binary)

*Note: the versions above are multi-threaded, historically there where single-threaded versions as well but these have fallen away.*

**The errors**

You are getting these errors because the options are being mixed and hence there are multiple definitions for symbols - one from the dll's import library and one from the static library. Which one should the linker choose? It is unable to determine an outcome given the conflict, hence the errors.

> ... which runtime library option should be selected if I want to link few openCV libraries statically and few dynamically...?

Don't mix them. It causes errors such as these that you are dealing with. The general advice with linking C++ (and C code) is to be consistent with respect to how the runtime is linked in.

I generally go further to detail that there should be a consistency between the linking of all libraries, either all static or all dynamic (sure they can be mixed, but this should not be done without a deep understanding of the memory and resource issues involved - generally it is not worth the risk).

Comment: So, if I use Static libraries of OpenCV then, somehow I am bound to use static runtime libraries of C++ too...is it so?? But that will increase the size of executable, isn't it? And, why there is a confusion to the compiler in the first place? When I have already specified in the VS settings that I want to use `/Md` for runtime then, why is it checking the static runtime also of C++?? Is the reason of conflict is the fact I have specified to use `Md` runtime and the Static OpenCV libraries have already attached Static runtime libraries of C++?

Comment: Yes. If the OpenCV libraries have already been built with the static runtime libraries, then you will have to use them as well. The compile switches /MD etc just add some instructions such that the linker knows which libraries to link in, so if there are two, then there is an error. It doesn't "force" one over the other (I think it affects some other code generation as well). So yes, the reason for the conflict is that you specify /MD and the OpenCV libraries have specified /MT.

Comment: @user2756695. On the file size, yes the static libraries will make the exe bigger, but it could make the total size of all the binaries (exe and dll) smaller.

Comment: did not understand your last comment. Which total size (i mean, which exe and dll) are you mentioning in the comment above?

Comment: @user2756695. I mean the file size being the exe size you were concerned about being large.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, the difference between dynamic linked libraries (dll) and static libraries is that static libraries are always compiled into your code and therefore loaded in memory statically with the executable, whereas dlls are loaded in memory as needed and need not be compiled into your code as long as their functions are properly referenced.

What seems to be happening in your case is that your static libraries are re-defining some functions that are already defined in the included dll and/or expecting functions from the dll that it does not contain.

Depending on the licencing and your needs, I have found that it is best practice when using external libraries to use dll's as they can (often) be updated without recompiling your code, which makes patching a simpler task.

Comment: thanks for your answer but it does not answer my question. I am talking about the conflict between Runtime libaries and the static libraries of OpenCV. As, you can find a lot of literature which says that the runtime libraries should not be confused with the dll libraries of a software etc.